# Python: How to combine the results of for loop into one output which extracted from json file?

Tags: json, python-3.x, arraylist

I extracted some values from Json file and the result is as follow.

```
[92.21372509012637]
[92.21372509012637]
[240.3532913296266]
[240.3532913296266]
[240.3532913296266]
[240.3532913296266]
```

I would like to get the result in a single list. as follow.

```
[92.21372509012637, 92.21372509012637, 240.3532913296266, 240.3532913296266, 240.3532913296266, 240.3532913296266]
```

Following is some part of my code.

```
for i in range(len(response_i['objcontent'][0]['rowvalues'])):

    lat = response_i['objcontent'][0]['rowvalues'][i][0]
    decoded=base64.b64decode(lat)
    if len(decoded)<9:
        a=struct.unpack('d',decoded)
        result=[]
        for i in a:
            result.append(i)
            print (result)
```

any one knows how can I fix this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: move `result = []` outside the loop.

Comment: Dear Jim, what do you mean by moving the result = [ ] outside the loop.

Comment: Move the line of code of the loop. What's not to understand?

Comment: If I remove result=[ ] i get the following error. " AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append' "

Comment: @p.sh, i don't think he's saying "remove".  He means write `result=[]` as the first line, outside the main `for` loop.  Right now, `result` is being reset.  Also move the `print` line outside the loop as well by deindenting it; otherwise it will print every iteration of your list instead of the final one.

Comment: @pylang, Thanks alot. I got the expected result.